# Problem with data transfer using USB power lines (so no data lines)

Tags: usb, usb-device, power-line-communication

I am using a Omnidots SWARM vibration sensor to measure vibrations on construction sides, works fine but I do need a battery from Omnidots in order to make it work off-grid and those batteries are quite expensive and also break quiet fast. That is why I am making my own battery pack with more capacity so I have to visit the sites less often.

But these sensors send the battery capacity live together with the sensor data to their online platform so I first thought that they used the USB-data lines to get the data form the battery (since the sensor is powered using a Micro-USB cable). But when I opened up the case of the original battery, it only had 2 wires (USB 5V + and USB -), but no data lines.

I tried to use my oscilloscope to get some image but had some hard time to get a good reading because I did noticed some difference but it was not much. It seems that it goes between 5V and ~4.7V (square wave) And the lower the battery capacity, the longer it takes to switch.

I first thought that got the solution, but that was not true because when I tried to replicated using an Arduino, MOSFET and my bench power supply, it just was stuck in a boot loop.

When I tried to put 5V directly from my PSU to the sensor, it was still stuck in a boot loop and then it got very strange. When I use a normal phone adapter using a normal micro-USB cable, it just worked (of course no battery data) but no boot loop! I even tried to get the voltage from my PSU as close as the voltage form my phone adapter, still boot loop.

I checked if my phone adapter was maybe creating a signal on the data lines that might trigger the sensor to go in some sort of debug/desktop mode.

But I didn't noticed any voltage on the dataline.

[image]

EDIT:

To make it clear, the sensor (Omnidots SWARM) does also send the signal. I uses 3G/4G to do this

[UPDATE]
I made some progress but for some reason i can't trick the sensor to send battery info. This is the signal that de original battery sends to the sensor
[image: OVERVIEW]
[image: LOW arround 4.6V]
[image: HIGH arround 4.9V]

And this what my custom print does
[image: OVERVIEW]
[image: LOW arround 4.6V]
[image: HIGH arround 4.9V]

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: it seems that you may be making an incorrect assumption ... it makes no sense for a device to report the USB voltage, since it is supposed to always be 5 V

Comment: You should be able to get a better look at that altering between 5V and 4.7V by selecting AC coupling on the scope.

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the response, it does sense something over those lines since it will display a correct batter capacity online when a battery is connected

Comment: @Unimportant ok i am not at home at the moment, i will try this tomorrow thanks for the tip

Comment: are you sure that it is the "sensor" and not the "pcb" that is doing the reporting?  In addition if it is reporting over a wireless connection, might there be a wireless link between the "pcb" and "sensor"?

Comment: I took the liberty to condense your question a bit – there was a bit much text that distracted from the question, but did not contribute helpful information.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.omnidots.com/en/downloads/technical-specifications-SWARM-Battery-V3/technical-specifications-SWARM-Battery-V3.pdf) the battery you are trying to replace?

Comment: @Abel the sensor does also send the signal using 3G/4G communication (i had to put that in my post, sorry...)

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes it is

Comment: You could try putting some tape over the data pins in the phone charger to make absolutely sure that the sensor isn't sensing these. Or use a USB cable without data wires.

Comment: @DamienD i just tried this. Also still works fine, so the phone charger does not send any signal over the data lines

Comment: @Unimportant i tried AC, it just showed a bunch of noise :/